# Lock feature when N taps reached per day

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add some code that locks or unlocks an app feature depending on the times a button is tapped per day.

So I f user taps button, for example, 3 times the feature is locked until next day. I am using some code for time control like this:

```
// My dates:
NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
NSDate * yesterday = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YESTERDAY"];
NSDate * refDate; // your reference date

// 10 first characters of description is the calendar date:
NSString * todayString = [[today description] substringToIndex:10];
NSString * yesterdayString = [[yesterday description] substringToIndex:10];
NSString * refDateString = [[refDate description] substringToIndex:10];

if ([refDateString isEqualToString:todayString])  {
    NSLog(@"Today");

} else if ([refDateString isEqualToString:yesterdayString])  {
    NSLog(@"Yesterday");

} else  {
    NSLog(@"%@", refDateString);
}
```

Now I should add the button action, but it is going to be a very ugly function. Does any body knows a pod for this purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way of beautify the NSDate function like this:

```
NSDate *lastButtonDate = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YESTERDAY"];
if(![[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:lastButtonDate]){
     // One day has passed away and we can store the new date
     NSDate *today= [NSDate date];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:today forKey:@"YESTERDAY"];
}
```

Now I need to add the button part, I mean, n times to lock the content I want to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is my last try of the function, it returns YES if the limit of button taps was reached and NO if it is not already reached.

```
- (BOOL)isContentLockedByTaps
{
    NSInteger buttonTaps = (NSInteger)[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonTaps"] integerValue] + 1;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", buttonTaps] forKey:@"buttonTaps"];
    NSLog(@"#### buttonTaps: %ld", (long)buttonTaps);

    NSDate *lastTimeButtonTapDate = (NSDate *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastTimeButtonTapDate"];
    if(![[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDateInToday:lastTimeButtonTapDate]){
        // Executed once per day. Save the first time the button is tapped.
        // And resets the button taps once per day.
        NSLog(@"#### Executed once per day");
        NSDate *today= [NSDate date];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:today forKey:@"lastTimeButtonTapDate"];
        // Reset & Update button taps.
        buttonTaps = 0;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", buttonTaps] forKey:@"buttonTaps"];
        // Content not locked
        return NO;

    }else{
        // Executed everytime except one time per day.
        NSLog(@"#### Executed everytime per day -1");
        if(buttonTaps > 3){
            NSLog(@"#### buttonTaps reached daily limit");
            // Content locked
            return YES;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"#### buttonTaps allowed");
            // Content not locked
            return NO;
        }
    }

    // Content locked by default
    return YES;
}
```